# ZK: keep session alive

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, zk

I have to redirect to a `tel:****` link in zk and after the user has finished the call, redirect him to another page. The problem is when I click on the link, ZK considers that I am going away the browser, and finishes automatically my client session (although I am really in the page but with the application stopped) sending the user to a Timeout page.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour without opening a new tab which I consider is a tricky solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue has been solved in ZK 7.0.4, please take a look at this [tracker](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-2506)